# How to share angular library that can change style

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm working in one angular project with some complex architecture and i would like to try to find the best way to share/changes styles

I would like to explain the architectue:

**1. Main application**: Is served to the client, the main application will have 80% of the functionalities, and will use one module (see 2) who have the rest of functionalities

**2. Module shared like library**: We have one library (is more like one module but build like a library) that will use in the main angular application, we have to make it because the main app is really big and the functionalities are not related *(is another team who develop this)*

**3. Ionic app**: Is like the main application but with less options, more mobile friendly and they will use the Module (they doest have the time to remake the module mobile friendly) *(is another team who develop this)*  They use their own style

**4. Library shared style for (1 2)**: We need the have the same style in the main application and the module, so we decide to make another project, this time like an real library, that will share the main style and components.

```
Library(4) -----used in--> module(2) --used in-----> ionic app (3)
           `                               `
            `----used in--------------------`----> main applcation (1)
```

Until here we doesn't have any problem, we manage to make it work, we had one only style BUT now, the main application will be propose in whites labels applications, so they will change the main style of the application

I want to know what are ours options, to share/edit the style in ours 1, 2, 4 and make it work in 3?

So my question is, i can make some kind of build in angular that can share the sass style between 4-2, 4-1, 2-4 and to be modify by variables in the main application (4)?

To explain it better, i would like to use the library (4) in the module (2), use the main style, and after that use the library (4), the module (2) in the main application (1) and use this one to configure the style of the next withe labels application? And use the module (2) in the ionic app (3) with the defaults values?

We already talk to use (host-theming + mix-in), to create in the library (3) the styles that can be used and give the functions to create it with the mix-in, but i see one big problem with this solutions, to add one new theme, i have to modify the library (3), use the new  version in the module (2), compile it to have the new theme and use the news versions of the module and library in the main application, and keep it compatible with the ionic app